# Need command help in Creating a Launcher in Xfce for Minecraft jar file

Tags: launcher, xfce, minecraft

Total Noob here. I've only discovered Linux to get Minecraft working on our Chromebook for my son. I know I need to learn more but really could use some step by step help here.

I am able to run Minecraft by clicking through the files, opening the program in the terminal and typing "java -jar Minecraft.jar" which works fine-- but this is for my 7 year old son so I'd like a little easier alternative.

I've tried creating an icon for running the Minecraft jar file on Xfce through "Creating a Launcher" but it does not work. I've tried various combinations of commands but some will not run at all and others will say it cannot find the file.

What exactly do i need to put in as the command and do i need to put anything in the "Working directory" box?

P.S. I apologize for the low quality pic, but I'm running two different machines right now with multiple windows and didn't feel like worrying about a regular screenshot through Linux.

[image: Screenshot of Linux desktop]